# A noncomplete inner product space may have a nonempty closed convex subset which does not have a unique element of minimal norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

It is well known that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $E$ is a nonempty closed convex subset of $H$, then there is a unique element in $E$ of minimal norm, i.e., a unique element $x_0\in E$ such that $\|x_0\|=\min _{x\in E} \|x\|$. (cf. Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 4.10) Its proof crucially uses completeness of $H$. I'm wondering if this fails if $H$ is not complete, but equipped with an inner product.

A counterexample when $H$ is a Banach sapce, is given in [Counterexamples to a theorem in Rudin's book on elements of smallest norm in a closed convex sets in a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043878/counterexamples-to-a-theorem-in-rudins-book-on-elements-of-smallest-norm-in-a-c). But in this counterexample, $C[0,1]$ is not an inner product space.

Is there a counterexample for a noncomplete innerproduct space?

Comment: I guess it is similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452638/counter-example-to-minimal-norm-theorem-for-hilbert-spaces/3452884#3452884

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Completeness needs to prove the existence part. I think that without completeness we still have the uniqueness part, see Brezis Theorem 5.2 Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDEs.